# Alexa responding before data is returned

Tags: node.js, lambda, promise, alexa-skills-kit

I'm new to promises, async/await, and Alexa/lambda so bear with me.

My function is returning prior to the data being returned. I had a similar issue where I was getting an error, but have since edited my function quite a bit and therefore asking a new question. I'm now no longer getting an error, but instead my data is being returned first, then the promise is executing.

I've tried re-writing the promise/function after reading many, many SO, google, and amazon developer forums. Nothing seems to be working for me.

```
const IntentRequest = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        const { requestEnvelope, serviceClientFactory, responseBuilder } = handlerInput;
        let responseData, promise;

         checkAuthenticationStatus(handlerInput,function(json){
            console.log('waited!')
            if(json.error) {
                return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(messages.NO_ACCESS).withSimpleCard('Unauthorized Request', messages.NO_ACCESS).getResponse();
            } else if(json.noerror && json.noerror.okay == 'true'){
                console.log('starting to get intent data')
                const url = new URL(json.noerror.okay.path);
                promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
                    console.log('start promise')
                   return httpsGetIntent(handlerInput, url).then((resultData) => {
                        console.log(resultData)
                        responseData = resultData;
                        resolve(responseData)
                        console.log('inside promise, no error, prior to return data')
                    })

            }).then((result) => { console.log('result', result)})
                return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak('Test').getResponse();
            }

        });
        console.log('response data', responseData)

        let result = await promise;
        return result;

    },
};
```

Out of my many console.logs() added for debugging, they print as follows:
- 'response data'
- 'waited!'
- 'starting to get intent data'
- 'start promise'
- resultData
- 'inside promise, no error, prior to return data'

Comment: As written, `return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak('Test').getResponse();` isn't inside a .then callback, despite indentation that makes it appear otherwise. There are other things to fix too.

Comment: Thanks @Roamer-1888! I actually solved this last night and am about to post my answer.

Answer (score 0):

While it's not fully fleshed out (I need to address the error handling portion) I wanted to share my solution here in case anyone stumbled upon this post and needed some help.

I moved the promise outside the checkAuthentication function and returned the data when it was processed. I then chained the promise with .then() and passed it the data returned, and prompted Alexa to speak.

```
const IntentRequest = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest';
    },
    async handle(handlerInput) {
        const { requestEnvelope, serviceClientFactory, responseBuilder } = handlerInput;
        let responseData, promise;
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            checkAuthenticationStatus(handlerInput, async function(json) {
                if (json.error) {
                    return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(messages.NO_ACCESS).withSimpleCard('Unauthorized Request', messages.NO_ACCESS).getResponse();
                } else if (json.noerror && json.noerror.okay == 'true') {
                    const url = new URL(json.noerror.okay.path);
                    let resultD = await httpsGetIntent(handlerInput, url, function(resultData) {
                        if (resultData) {
                            return resolve(resultData);
                        } else {
                            return resolve(handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak('False Test').getResponse());
                        }
                    })

                }
            })

        }).then((data) => {
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(data.response.outputSpeech.text).getResponse();
        });
    },
};
```

Comment: `httpsGetIntent()` is a bit confusing. On the one hand, you `await` it (indicating that it returns Promise) while on the other hand, it accepts a callback. Typically a function (or any particular call) will exhibit one behaviour or the other.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I appreciate the help! I don't totally understand async/await and was referencing some other alexa examples

Answer (score 0):

Almost_Ashleigh, based on your own answer, some ideas in which I have :

1. made the assumption that `httpsGetIntent()` returns a Promsie that delivers `resultData`.
2. promisified `checkAuthenticationStatus()` by writing the adaptor `checkAuthenticationStatusAsync()`.
3. consolidated the `.speak()` commands into  final `.then()` and `.catch()` clauses.
4. allowed specific errors to be tailored by decorating with a `.title` property, which is used in the final `.catch()` as a cardTitle. Any undecorated errors will default to 'Sorry' (or whatever you want).

```
// in a suitable scope ...
function checkAuthenticationStatusAsync(handlerInput) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) {
        checkAuthenticationStatus(handlerInput, (json) => {
            if (json.error || !json.noerror || json.noerror.okay !== 'true') {
                let err = new Error(messages.NO_ACCESS); // or maybe a separate error message per error case?
                err.title = 'Unauthorized Request';
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(json);
            }
        });
    });
}

// ... and ...
const IntentRequest = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {
        return checkAuthenticationStatusAsync(handlerInput)
        .then((json) => httpsGetIntent(handlerInput, new URL(json.noerror.okay.path)))
        .then((resultData) => {
            if (resultData) {
                // success path ends here
                return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(resultData.response.outputSpeech.text).getResponse();
            } else {
                throw new Error('No result data returned'); // throws to the .catch() below
            }
        })
        .catch(err => {
            // all errors end up here.
            return handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(err.message).withSimpleCard(err.title || 'Sorry', err.message).getResponse();
            throw err; // to keep handle's caller informed
        });
    },
};
```

Note, this is *a* way, not necessarily *the* way, to write the code. Please feel free to raid for ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Your best friend is async/await. Please use something like [this](https://gist.github.com/germanviscuso/ba0c8e5af0491a6cb88c39bd7cd5c0c7#file-index-js-L16) or like [this](https://github.com/germanviscuso/skill_quien_cumple_hoy/blob/master/lambda/logic.js#L39) to access APIs.

Comment: Thank you for these examples! I'll try to implement them